# Using preg_replace to character Japanese

Tags: php, regex, cjk

Basically I translated a string from english to japan like this:

```
$test1 = 1104 Notes receivable
$test2 = 1104 受取手形
```

My Goal is to remove the number on front of string. I use this regeX:

```
preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z]+/', '', $test1)
output : Notes receivable
```

Now , how about the japanese ?
I need this string : `受取手形`

Comment: If you need to only remove the digits and spaces at the start, you may use `preg_replace('/^[\d\s]+/u', '', $test2)`

Comment: How about other languages? `1104 نت های قابل دریافت` ? What behavior do you expect?

Answer (score 4):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/faAoWz/1)

```
^\P{L}+
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/bxZiVY)

```
<?php

$strings = ["1104 Notes receivable", "1104 受取手形"];
foreach($strings as &$string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/^\P{L}+/', "", $string);
}
var_dump($strings);
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line.
- `\P{L}+` Matches any character that `\p{L}` does not (equivalent to `[^\p{L}]`), one or more times. `\p{L}` is a Unicode character class that matches any letter in any language/script.